# 400 Bad request when sending XML to WCF

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I'm trying to post some XML to a web service and every time I do, I get a 400 Bad Request error back.

In MyService.cs:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://foo")]
public class MyService
{

    [OperationContract, WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetData/", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method = "POST")]
    public string GetData(DataRequest req)
    {
        return "Success!";
    }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://foo")]
public class DataRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

In a separate console application Program.cs:

```
    Path p = "C:\\Users\\sflan\\Desktop\\test.xml";
    string url = "http://foo/MyService.svc/GetData/";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/xml";

    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(p.readFile());
    req.ContentLength = data.Length;
    using (Stream s = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        s.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        s.Close();
    }

    try
    {
        WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rdr.ReadToEnd());
            rdr.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
```

The XML I'm trying to send in the file:

```
<root>
    <Users ID="2" Data="This is some sample data." />
</root>
```

I've searched around for hours looking for a solution, but have been unable to find one.  My web.config allows max buffer size / poolsize and everything relevant I've been able to find, but still no luck.  It's worth noting that if I remove "DataRequest req" from my GetData method signature, I get my success message, but I need to be able to work with the XML data.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The XML was poorly formatted, something I wasn't picking up from posts centered on the same issue.

The proper XML for this is as follows:

```
 <DataRequest xmlns="http://foo">
      <Data>This is some sample data.</Data>
      <ID>2</ID>
 </DataRequest>
```